# C++ 2a - polymorphic range

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual-functions, c++20, c++-concepts

I am writing a C++ library and have had this *amazing* idea of using as much C++2a/C++20 as possible. Thus, I am using the standard library concepts and creating my own. However, the idea of a function returning a `std::vector<X>` seemed non-C++20 enough to me, so I declared in my concept a return type matching `std::ranges::view<X>`. I've then implemented some classes that fulfill this concept.

However, the problem appeared when I wanted to devise a polymorphic wrapper class. So, let's say the concept is `C` and I have three implementing classes `C1`, `C2` and `C3` (but allow for more). Now I want to create a class `C_virtual` and a template `C_virtual_impl<C c>` deriving from it, which will allow me to refer to all classes fulfilling `C` polymorphically. However, for that to work I need a polymorphic `std::ranges::view` wrapper, similar in spirit to `C_virtual`.

I have not seen any such class in the headers and in C++ reference. Moreover, when I started implementing it myself, I quickly found myself unable to due to some requirements on iterators, in particular default constructibility, swappability and similar.

Is there a nonobvious solution in the standard library or an idiom? If not, how do I deal with the problem? Possibly a change of design will work. I certainly do not want to return a `std::vector<X>` or to return a `V<X>` where `V` would be a type parameter of `C`. How do I do this?

Comment: Concepts are useful exactly because of, and in places that, inheritance-based polymorphism is not really working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Range views, and many other template techniques, are not meant to be used with inheritance-based polymorphism. This is much like how `vector<BaseClass>` is not especially useful.

If you need runtime polymorphism, then the tool you want is not inheritance (directly); it's type erasure. That is, you have some view wrapper which uses type erasure to forward the various view operations to the erased type. This would also need to be paired with type-erased iterators that wrap the iterators of the given view.

Now of course, this means that the characteristics of the view have to be defined by the type erased wrapper. The wrapper could implement the `input_range` concept, but it could never fulfill more than `input_range` itself. Even if you put a `contiguous_range` type in the wrapper, the wrapper will limit the interface to that of an `input_range`.

As such, it's best to just avoid this case and rely on static polymorphism via templates whenever possible.